# Changing JUST .scale in UIImage?

Tags: swift, uiimage

Here, I'm creating a typical graphic (it's full-screen size, on all devices) on the fly...

```
func buildImage()->UIImage
        {
        let wrapperA:UIView = say, a picture
        let wrapperB:UIView = say, some text to go on top
                
        let mainSize = basicImage.bounds.size
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mainSize, false, 0.0)
        
        basicImage.drawHierarchy(in: basicImage.bounds, afterScreenUpdates:true)
        wrapperA.drawHierarchy(in: wrapperA.bounds, afterScreenUpdates:true)
        wrapperB.drawHierarchy(in: wrapperB.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        
        let result:UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        // so we've just created a nice big image for some reason,
        // no problem so far

        print( result?.scale  )
        
        // I want to change that image to have a scale of 1.
        // I don't know how to do that, so I actually just
        // make a new identical one, with scale of 1
        
        let resultFixed:UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: result!.cgImage!,
                            scale: 1.0,
                            orientation: result!.imageOrientation)
        
        print( resultFixed.scale )
        
        print("Let's use only '1-scale' images to upload to things like Instagram")
        
        // return result
        return resultFixed
        
        // be sure to ask on SO if there's a way to
        // just "change the scale" rather than make new.
        }
```

I need the final image to be `.scale` of 1 - but `.scale` is a read only property.

The only thing I know how to do is make a whole new image copy ... but set the scale to 1 as it's being created.

Is there a better way?

---

## Handy tip -

This was motivated by: say you're saving a large image to the user's album, and also allowing UIActivityViewController so as to post to (example) Instagram. As a general rule, it seems to be best to make the scale 1 before sending to (example) Instagram; if the scale is say 3 you actually just get the top-left 1/3 of the image on your Instagram post. In terms of saving it to the iOS photo album, it does seem to be harmless (perhaps, better in some ways) to set the scale to 1. (I only say "better" as, if the image is, example, ultimately say emailed to a friend on PC, it can cause less confusion if the scale is 1.) Interestingly though, if you just use the iOS Photos album, and take a scale 2 or 3 image, and share it to Instagram: it does in fact appear properly on Instagram! (perhaps Apple's Photos indeed knows it os best to make it scale 1, before sending it to somewhere like Instagram!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the `scale` property of `UIImage` is read-only – therefore you cannot change it directly.

However, using `UIImage`'s `init(cgImage:scale:orientation)` initialiser doesn't *really* copy the image – the underlying `CGImage` that it's wrapping (which contains the actual bitmap data) is still the same instance. It's only a new `UIImage` wrapper that is created.

Although that being said, you could cut out the intermediate `UIImage` wrapper in this case by getting the `CGImage` from the context directly through `CGContext`'s [`makeImage()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcontext/1454225-makeimage) method. For example:

```
func buildImage() -> UIImage? {

    // ...

    let mainSize = basicImage.bounds.size

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mainSize, false, 0.0)
    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

    // get the current context
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }

    // -- do drawing here --

    // get the CGImage from the context by calling makeImage() – then wrap in a UIImage
    // through using Optional's map(_:) (as makeImage() can return nil)
    // by default, the scale of the UIImage is 1.
    return context.makeImage().map(UIImage.init(cgImage:))
}
```

Comment: As a side note, I would recommend against force unwrapping the resultant image – and instead handle the case where the image could not be created. In this example, I'm returning `nil` to the caller.

Comment: (2) ahh .. you're saying, instead of where I go `let result:UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` ... in fact I can instead use this 'makeImage()' on the current context which returns a CGImage - and then use UIImage.init to wrap it to a UIImage ... excellent!

Comment: @JoeBlow Precisely :)

Comment: Amazingly knowledgeable answer, thanks again @Hamish

Answer (score 0):

btw you can change scale of result image throw creating new image

```
let newScaleImage = UIImage(cgImage: oldScaleImage.cgImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation: oldScaleImage.imageOrientation)
```